# Product Attribute not showing on the Front End

Tags: magento-1.9

I have been trying to get an option to appear, on the front end. I can see the attribute in the back end of Magento. It is a **text field** I have entered some default values in to the text field and saved it.

I have reindex the site and flushed the cache, and cleared my browser cache, but I cannot see my new attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to print the attribute in the **.phtml** file ( for example:

`$product->getData('attribute_code') or $product->getAttributeCode()` )

Comment: Thanks, I will give this a try, as I am not sure why its not showing up in the front end, but this maybe the case.

Answer (score 1):

go to `catalog > manage attributes`   & click on the attribute you want to display in frontend , than you can see `Frontend Properties` below that you can see : `Visible on Product View Page on Front-end`  to yes.
[image]

Comment: I have check that and I had already set that to Yes

Answer (score 1):

You can use these codes with label or without label:

Without label name:

```
<?php echo $_product->getAttributeText('brand'); ?>
```

With label name (Brand Name):

```
<?php $brandname = $_product->getAttributeText('brand');
 if (trim($brandname)) {
   echo "Brand Name" .$this->htmlEscape($brandname);
 }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I thought it would be helpful to post.

In this situation you need to edit the attribute labels accessed via the Associated Products tab in the configurable product settings.